# Get Row data from DataGridView of form1 to form2 TextBox without opening form 2 again

Tags: c#, datagridview, textbox

I have two forms, `form1` (containing `Textbox`) and `form2` (containing `DataGridView` and button). Now I want to pass one of the selected row data from `form2` to `form1`. But the problem is that I don't want to open `form1` again. When I click on button it will update Textbox only.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In Form2 declare a string value and pass the dataGridView's value to it from dataGridView's CellEnter event:

`private void dataGridView2_CellEnter(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
        {
        sText = dataGridView2.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].Value.ToString();
        }`

In Form1 create a public method that will retreive and display this data:

`public void GetAndDisplay(string sText)
  {
    textBox1.Text = sText;
  }`

You will need to add a property in Form2 to define Form1 as Form2's parent:

`public Form1 fParent {get; set;}`

And then when calling it from Form1 you will have to do it this way:

`Form2 f2 = new Form2();
 f2.fParent = this;
 f2.Show();`

And in the end, you call the GetAndDisplay method from Form2's button:

`fParent.GetAndDisplay(sText);`